# Strange accuracy difference between ipython and ipython notebook then using fortran module with f2py

Tags: python, fortran, ipython, f2py

I'm encountering a strange accuracy difference between ipython and the ipython notebook when using a fortran module compiled with f2py.

My fortran module is:

```
subroutine tt(string,fmt,n_num,out)
  implicit none
  INTEGER,INTENT(IN)::n_num
  CHARACTER(LEN=*),INTENT(IN)::string
  CHARACTER(LEN=*),INTENT(IN)::fmt
  DOUBLE PRECISION,INTENT(OUT)::out(n_num)
  read(string,fmt) out
end subroutine tt
```

Compiling with: `f2py -c -m andre tt.f90`

In ipython i get:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np
In [2]: import andre
In [3]: out = np.array(andre.tt(' 0.34 4.56 5.67','(3f5.2)',3),dtype=np.float)
In [4]: print out
    [ 0.34  4.56  5.67]
```

which is the desired output. However, in the ipython notebook, using the same code, I get:

```
print out
print out+0.0001
[ 0.  4.  5.]
[  1.00000000e-04   4.00010000e+00   5.00010000e+00]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try to do `print(repr(out[0]))` to see a bit more digits? Maybe it's just ipython notebook having a different set of options regarding the **displaying** of the results.

Comment: That is what I tried to see with the second print statement. I tested your sugestion: `print(repr(out[0]))` which gave me `0.0`. So it seem that something is left somewhere. Is the ipython notebook supposed to work with such modules? Or are there some ZMQ restrictions?

Comment: Can you check the numpy version for ipython notebook and ipython?  (`print np.__version__`).  Are they the same?  (I don't know anything about `ipython` and how it works).

Comment: They are both `1.7.0` versions. I'm working on a Fedora 18 Box using the 64bit version. I might just check weather I see the same result in Firefox/Chrome/Opera. -> I see the same behavior in Firefox and Google Chrome.

Comment: Also, it looks to me like your fortran format is wrong.  Shouldn't it be `'(3(1X,f4.2))'`? (although, if that's the case, ipython and ipython notebook should handle it the same ...)

Comment: '(f5.2)' should work fine, fore these number it add some white space to make them more human readable

Comment: The Problem was solved using the oldest method ever: "Have you tried to switch it on an off?". A restart of my box solved the problem. However, should this happen? I post this as an comment since I'm to much of a youngling to answer my own question.

Comment: I think that like C modules, Fortran ones can't be reloaded, so you probably had a wrong version in memory or cached somewhere.

Comment: Not really, I killed my Kernel every so often ..

Comment: It certainly *shouldn't* happen. But there's ~ no way that IPython would alter the result of computations done inside it.