# what is the fastest way in python to convert a string with formatted numbers in an numpy array

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I have a large ASCII file (~100GB) which consists of roughly 1.000.000 lines of known formatted numbers which I try to process with python. The file is too large to read in completely into memory, so I decided to process the file line by line:

```
fp = open(file_name)
for count,line in enumerate(fp):
    data = np.array(line.split(),dtype=np.float)
    #do stuff
fp.close()
```

It turns out, that I spend most of the run time of my program in the `data =` line. Are there any ways to speed up that line? Also, the execution speed seem much slower than what I could get from an native FORTRAN program with formated read (see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15834327/strange-accuracy-difference-between-ipython-and-ipython-notebook-then-using-fort), I've implemented a FORTRAN string processor and used it with f2py, but the run time was only comparable with the `data =` line. I guess the I/O handling and type conversions between Python/FORTRAN killed what I gained from FORTRAN)

Since I know the formatting, shouldn't there be a better and faster way as to use `split()`? Something like:

```
data = readf(line,'(1000F20.10)')
```

I tried the [fortranformat](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fortranformat) package, which worked well, but in my case was three times slower than thee `split()` approach.

P.S. As suggested by ExP and root I tried the np.fromstring and made this quick and dirtry benchmark:

```
t1 = time.time()
for i in range(500):
  data=np.array(line.split(),dtype=np.float)
t2 = time.time()    
print (t2-t1)/500
print data.shape
print data[0]
0.00160977363586
(9002,)
0.0015162509
```

and:

```
t1 = time.time()
for i in range(500):    
   data = np.fromstring(line,sep=' ',dtype=np.float,count=9002)
t2 = time.time()
print (t2-t1)/500
print data.shape
print data[0]
0.00159792804718
(9002,)
0.0015162509
```

so `fromstring` is in fact slightly slower in my case.

Comment: You should check out the [timeit](http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) module for testing these little snippets.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [`numpyp.fromstring`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromstring.html)?

```
np.fromstring(line, dtype=np.float, sep=" ")
```

Comment: Yes, the speed is about the same as the `split()` approach. I guess to really speed things up format codes must be "natively" used.

Comment: @root ok I will try this again, maybe I missed something

Answer (score 1):

The [*np.genfromtxt*](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) function is a speed champion if you can get it to match you input format.

If not, then you may already be using the fastest method.  Your line-by-line split-into-array approach exactly matches the [SciPy Cookbook examples](http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/InputOutput).

Comment: From my understanding `np.genfromtext` will try to read the whole file into memory which is not possible in this case (file is ~100GB).

Comment: It would be sad if this is the fastest method. I don't like to spend/waste so much time and CPU cycles on something that in my opinion should be fast and straight forward (i.e. using the known format code) - but maybe I'm too much influenced by FORTRAN.

Comment: @Andre no need to read the whole file into memory. You can use as `fname` argument also a generator that yields line per line from a simple while loop.